# About C# and Inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have a theorical/pratical question about how inheritance works in C#.

Let's say that I have to model some autos, so I have a few common methods that all the autos must implement and a pilot should know. In code-words this should be an Interface:

```
interface Automobile {
   void speedup();
   void break();
   void steer();
   //bla bla
}
```

Now, all kind of car should have some common technical implementations beside the actions that a pilot can perform over them, let's say the property fuelLevel, at this point I still don't want to know how a car speeds up or breaks down, so I would wrote:

```
 abstract class Car : Automobile {
    int fuelLevel;    // for example....
    public abstract void speedup();
    public abstract void break();
    public abstract void steer();
 }
```

Now I want to model a Ferrari, so:

```
class Ferrari : Car {
    public void speedup() { ... }
    public void break() { ... }
    public void steer() { ... }
}
```

Now, in Java this code should work (changing some syntax), but in C# won't because it says:

```
Error   1   'Ferrari' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Car.speedup()'
Error   1   'Ferrari' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Car.break()'
Error   1   'Ferrari' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Car.steer()'
```

Why? How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to mark the methods with `override` to cover the `abstract` definitions beneath:

```
class Ferrari : Car 
{
    public override void speedup() { }
    public override void break() { }
    public override void steer() { }
}
```

Other than that, you're set - the `Ferrari` class will satisfy your interface, even though the methods are derived.  Also as an aside, naming in C# is slightly different:

- Prefix interfaces with `I`, `IAutomobile`.
- Capital letters on methods: `Speedup()`, `Break()`, `Steer()`.

Comment: I guess this is one of the differences between Java and C#... Thank you so much.

Comment: @IssamTP actually according to the times on the site, it only took me 3 minutes to answer :-)

Comment: Yep but I tried to accept the ans. as soon as I've seen it, but I couldn't because the system said: "You can't accept an answer bla bla 7 minutes"...

Comment: @ IssamTP  I thought you forget to accept the answer... cant stop myself to comment for that...

Answer (score 3):

You are actually ignoring to override abstract class members. Try to consider something like:

```
interface IAutomobile
{
    void Steer();
    void Break();
}

abstract class Car : IAutomobile
{
    public abstract void Steer();
    public abstract void Break();
}

class Ferrari : Car
{
    public override void Steer()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Break()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: @IssamTP that's an automatic default implementation of the methods, so that even without you providing an implementation it will compile, no matter if the method should return a value or not.

Answer (score 1):

well, "disconnetti" (are you italian?) method is not written anywhere, so you must before explain us where that comes from.

Second, In C# when you override an abstract method, you must explicit it through the *override* keyword

Comment: Yep I'm italian, the real code is slightly different from the posted because this example was easier to understand and to explain. Anyway I edited the code quite soon...

Comment: Ok, the answer is just that you need override keyword by the way, as I've written (and others too). Buona fortuna col codice ;)